# jQuery Slimscroll to HTML table with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

I am researching my way to use slimscroll plugin to apply to html table, which is getting filled with the business data from a web service. However as the title depicts, slimscroll scroll the entire div and header of table too. I am trying to achieve fixed header with tbody scrolling.

```
<div class="slimscrolldiv">
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    . . . . .
  </table>
</div>
```

I am not posting any code but above code snippet would suffice to understand the problem. If need any other information, please post a comment.

Comment: now whole table got slim scroll property??

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/JcdrQ/)

this is alternate way :

```
<div class="slimscrolldiv">
   <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody id="scrollMe">
        <tr>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#scrollMe').slimScroll({
      height: '250px'
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for setting up the fiddle; however it does not solve my problem as I have to scroll entire tbody not single table. It just not look ok to add it for each td

Comment: I have  a table with multiple columns, when I call slimscroll on tbody it shrinks my columns to single columns. This is my fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/qLrywhmt/

Comment: I don't know why this answer is upvoted, as it does not solve the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that worked for me (at least partially)
was to create 2 tables, 
one for thead
and one for tbody
and to wrap the slimscroll around the tbody table.

The reason this works 'partially' is because you then have to play around with css to get the 2 table columns to line up.